# Remove gzip encoding in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: kubernetes, azure-storage, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I have been facing a performance delay in AKS when trying to download the details from Azure blob.  When i try do the same from GKE, it is very fast. The only difference is AKS has gzip and GKE has no gzip header.

So i would like to remove gzip encoding from the AKS and I have tried the below settings in the kubernetes ingress file, but no luck.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-gzip: "false"
nginx.org/server-snippet: gzip off;
nginx.org/server-snippets: gzip off;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accodring to [this](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#use-gzip) it should be:

```
use-gzip: false
```

but this has to go to the [nginx ingress config map](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/customization/custom-configuration/#custom-configuration), not on the ingress file

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41. Changing the code to configmap removes the gzip. But, there is no improvement in the performance.

Comment: well, you should raise a new question for this, since it would be a different one. this one is answered :) should probably accept\upvote this one :)

Comment: Hi, recently I am facing the same problem as yours, I would like to ask how do you link your modified config map (which has use-gzip information) to your nginx ingress? I appreciate it if you could give me some hints.